# Insert a date with offset into PostgreSQL database using Python code

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

I'm creating a little code to insert info into my database. However I don't know how to make it work. What I want in this code is that the user inputs the tool name and the customer ID. Then once these two inputs are allocated, I want the current date and the rental date which will be the current date plus 10 days. The rental date and current date need to be automatically inserted once the user finished typing the customer ID.

```
import psycopg2
try:
    print "Connecting to the 'Tools_Rental' Database...."
    connection = psycopg2.connect(database = "tool_store_ghah0004", user = "dbadmin")

except:
  print "Error: Connection was unsuccessful"
  sys.exit(1)

else:
     print "Connected Succesfully!"

from datetime import date
today = date.today()

start = raw_input("Would you like to enter the main menu ?[y/n]")
while == "y":
 Menu = raw_input("if you would you like to enter the sub-menu, please enter 2")
 if Menu == "2":
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   query_tools()
   InsertTool = raw_input("Please choose the tool that you want to rent.\n")
   query_customers()
   InsertCusID = raw_input("Please insert one of the customer IDs above .\n")
   returnDate = today + "10"
   insert_tool = """insert into rentals(tool_id, customer_id, rental_date, return_date)values ((select tool_id from tools where tool_name = %s), (select customer_id from customers where customer_id = %s), %s, %s)"""
   val = (InsertTool, InsertCusID, InsertRentalD, InsertcurrentD)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.timedelta` to add time intervals to both `datetime.date` and `datetime.date`. You can compute your date with:

```
from datetime import timedelta

returnDate = today + timedelta(10)
```

Alternatively, you can also calculate the date in the SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO rentals (tool_id, customer_id, rental_date, return_date) VALUES (
    (select tool_id from tools where tool_name = %s), 
    (select customer_id from customers where customer_id = %s), 
    CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE + 10)
)
```

and you should omit the date parameters from the call.